# Android - keyevent for hide the softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

how to override the key event "hide keyboard button" that present in the on screen keyboard in Android. Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8800671/781553) post. Haven't tried it.